# Next JS build isn't building out every path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**Summary / Issue**

I've created an anime database app using `Nextjs` with deployment on `Vercel`. The build was fine and the initial page rendered, but only a few of my dynamic routes are being rendered, the rest display a 404 page. I went into the deploy log and found that for each dynamic page, only 10 routes were being built for every dynmaic route.

**Deploy Screenshot from Vercel**

[image]

While working in development (localhost:3000), there were no issues and everything ran fine.

The routes are based on the `id` of each title and there are thousands of titles.

**My Code**

Here is my code for one of the pages using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const [anime, animeCharacters, categories, streaming, reviews] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/characters`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/categories`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/streaming-links`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/reviews`),
  ])
    .then((responses) =>
      Promise.all(responses.map((response) => response.json()))
    )
    .catch((e) => console.log(e, "There was an error retrieving the data"))

  return { props: { anime, animeCharacters, categories, streaming, reviews } }
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime")
  const anime = await res.json()

  const paths = anime.data.map((show) => ({
    params: { id: show.id },
  }))

  return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

`[id]` is my dynamic route and as you can see, it's only being populated with 10 routes (the first 3 and 7 additional).

Despite the number of shows, I'm looping over each show and grabbing its ID and then passing that as the path.

**What I've thought of**

The API I'm using is the [Kitsu](https://kitsu.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/json-api/request-headers) API.

Within the docs, it states: "Resources are paginated in groups of 10 by default and can be increased to a maximum of 20". I figured this might be why 10 paths are being generated, but if that was the case, then why would it work fine in production and in deployment? Also, when I click on each poster image, it should bring me to that specific title by its `id`, whihc is dynamic, so it shouldn't matter how many recourses are being generated initially.

**Code for dynamic page `/anime/[id]**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch"
import formatedDates from "./../../helpers/formatDates"

import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar"
import TrailerVideo from "../../components/TrailerVideo"
import Characters from "./../../components/Characters"
import Categories from "../../components/Categories"
import Streamers from "../../components/Streamers"
import Reviews from "../../components/Reviews"

const Post = ({ anime, animeCharacters, categories, streaming, reviews}) => {
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false)

  const handleReadMore = () => setReadMore((prevState) => !prevState)

  let {
    titles: { en, ja_jp },
    synopsis,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    ageRating,
    ageRatingGuide,
    averageRating,
    episodeCount,
    posterImage: { small },
    coverImage,
    youtubeVideoId,
  } = anime.data.attributes

  const defaultImg = "/cover-img-default.jpg"

  const synopsisSubString = () =>
    !readMore ? synopsis.substring(0, 240) : synopsis.substring(0, 2000)

  const router = useRouter()
  if(router.isFallback) return <div>loading...</div>

  return (
    <div className='relative'>
      <div className='z-0'>
        <img
          className='absolute mb-4 h-12 min-h-230 w-full object-cover opacity-50'
          src={!coverImage ? defaultImg : coverImage.large}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='relative container z-50'>
        <Navbar />

        <div className='mt-16 flex flex-wrap md:flex-no-wrap'>
          {/* Main  */}
          <div className='md:max-w-284'>
            <img className='z-50 mb-6' src={small} />

            <div className='xl:text-lg pb-6'>
              <h1 className='mb-2'>Anime Details</h1>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <span className='font-bold'>Japanese Title:</span> {ja_jp}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span className='font-bold'>Aired:</span>{" "}
                  {formatedDates(startDate, endDate)}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span className='font-bold'>Rating:</span> {ageRating} /{" "}
                  {ageRatingGuide}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span className='font-bold'>Episodes:</span> {episodeCount}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <Streamers streaming={streaming} />
          </div>

          {/* Info Section */}
          <div className='flex flex-wrap lg:flex-no-wrap md:flex-1 '>
            <div className='mt-6 md:mt-40 md:ml-6 lg:mr-10'>
              <h1 className='sm:text-3xl pb-1'>{en}</h1>
              <h2 className='sm:text-xl lg:text-2xl pb-4 text-yellow-600'>
                {averageRating}{" "}
                <span className='text-white text-base lg:text-lg'>
                  Community Rating
                </span>
              </h2>
              <div>
                <p className='max-w-2xl pb-3 overflow-hidden xl:text-lg'>
                  {synopsisSubString()}
                  <span className={!readMore ? "inline" : "hidden"}>...</span>
                </p>
                <button
                  className='text-teal-500 hover:text-teal-900 transition ease-in-out duration-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline'
                  onClick={handleReadMore}
                >
                  {!readMore ? "Read More" : "Read Less"}
                </button>
              </div>
              <Categories categories={categories} />
              <Reviews reviews={reviews}/>
            </div>

            {/* Sidebar */}
            <section className='lg:max-w-sm mt-10 md:ml-6 lg:ml-0'>
              <TrailerVideo youtubeVideoId={youtubeVideoId} />
              <Characters animeCharacters={animeCharacters} />
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const [anime, animeCharacters, categories, streaming, reviews] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/characters`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/categories`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/streaming-links`),
    fetch(`https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime/${params.id}/reviews`),
  ])
    .then((responses) =>
      Promise.all(responses.map((response) => response.json()))
    )
    .catch((e) => console.log(e, "There was an error retrieving the data"))

  return { props: { anime, animeCharacters, categories, streaming, reviews } }
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime")
  const anime = await res.json()

  const paths = anime.data.map((show) => ({
    params: { id: show.id },
  }))

  return { paths, fallback: true }
}

export default Post
```

**Screenshot of Errror**

[image]

[**Repo**](https://github.com/dvlprdave/Kintsugi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the API you are working with serves resources in groups of 10, then when you call the API in `getStaticPaths` you only have 10 `id` ahead of time. Using static generation in nextjs builds static pages for all the available ids ahead of time in production mode. But when in development mode your server will recreate each page on per request basis. So to solve this problem you can build the first 10 pages and make the rest of the pages to be fallback. Here is how you do it.

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime")
  const anime = await res.json()

  // you can make a series of calls to the API requesting 
  // the next page to get the desired amount of data (100 or 1000)
  // how many ever static pages you want to build ahead of time

  const paths = anime.data.map((show) => ({
    params: { id: show.id },
  }))

  // this will generate 10(resource limit if you make 1 call because your API returns only 10 resources) 
  // pages ahead of time  and rest of the pages will be fallback
  return { paths, fallback: true }
}
```

Keep in mind when using `{fallback: true}` in `getStaticPaths` you need have some sort of loading indicator because the page will be statically generated when you make a request for the first time which will take some time(usually very fast).

In your page that you want to statically generate

```
function MyPage = (props) {

  const router = useRouter()

  if (router.isFallback) {
    // your loading indicator
    return <div>loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    // the normal logic for your page
  )
}
```

P.S. I forgot to mention how to handle errors where API responds with 404 or 500 and the resource doesn't exist to send as props when using fallback in static generation.

So here's how to do it.

```
const getStaticProps = async () => {
  // your data fetching logic

  // if fail
  return {
    props: {data: null, error: true, statusCode: 'the-status-code-you-want-to-send-(500 or 404)'} 
  }  

  // if success 
  return {
    props: {data: 'my-fetched-data', error: false} 
  }

}

// in the page component
import ErrorPage from 'next/error';

function MyStaticPage(props) {
  if (props.error) {
   return <ErrorPage statusCode={404}/>
  }

  // else you normal page logic
}
```

Let me know if it helped or you encountered some error while implementing.
Here is where you can learn more https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation

Comment: Thank you. I had a lack of understanding using the fallback key. I implemented the suggestion and went to build and received the following error: "Error occurred prerendering page "/anime/[id]". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". I checked to see if it worked within development, and it did, but not in production. I'll update my question to include the full code for the dynamic page.

Comment: That error is very common during the static generation that happens because you are using some data from the API response in your code which is possibly null or undefined or does not exist as a field in the response. Try running `yarn build` or `npm run build` locally and see if it success. If it fails take a screenshot an share it. I might be able to pin point the exact issue.

Comment: Still, the same error. I've added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: Well the error is kinda vague. I was not expecting that. I think the error occurs when you destructure the properties of anime.data.attributes. Can you `console.log(anime)` and confirm that anime.data.attribute exists. Also if you can share the screenshot of the build log in production that might show some error info that could help.

Comment: Also, I edited the answer to explain more on how to handle 404 or 500 error from the API call in `getStaticProps` and render an error page accordingly.

Comment: I logged out `anime` and I'm getting back the expected data. Also, the production screenshot shows the same exact error, nothing is different at all.

Comment: I've added a link to the repo in the question.

Comment: Here you go everything is fixed. Build works like a charm. [solution](https://pastebin.com/E4zz6hZh). You need to edit only the anime/[id].js file according to the solution nothing else needed.

Comment: It's always the simplest of things. I appreciate you taking out the time to help me!

Comment: @subashMahapatra can you tell what is the 'solution' you are mentioned above? The link is not awailable. I run into the same issue and waste long time

Comment: @northernwind There was a bug in the actual code **not build related** which I helped the OP fix when I was working on the solution for his issue. The solution link was for the modified file. The bug was due to not checking `router.isFallback` before trying to render the content for the fallback page using the props. The only modified file was the `anime/[id].js`.

Comment: @northernwind There was no extra details on explaining the answer or link to a codesandbox in the "solution" link, it was just the raw modified file. The answer was edited to have a proper solution for the issue the OP was having at that moment. If you have worked through the answer and can't find a fix for your issue please consider posting a question(which I recommend) with the details of the issue you're having.